# Stylesheet conflicting with jquery ui style

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-css-framework

I have the following style which works as I want it to work:

```
.container { font-family:arial; text-decoration:none; font-size:12px; }

.title {color:#707070; text-decoration:none; }
.username {color:#8DAAB8;}
.dateandtime {color:#A5A7AC;}

.container:hover .title { color: #000000; }
.container:hover .username { color: #DF821B; }
.container:hover .dateandtime { color: #3185B6; }
```

But for some reason, when I add the following style to my page (which I need):

```
<link type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

The `.title` class in the original style above stops working, and it remains `#000000` for some reason.  It should be `#707070` in normal state, and `#000000` when hovered over.

Why is this happening when I add the external style sheet and how do I stop this from happening without removing the external style sheet?

As soon as I remove the external stylesheet, the `.title` class starts working perfectly again, but the rest of the page, `jquery-ui-tabs`, `jquery-ui-sortables` stop working properly.

Comment: you need to post your html in order to get an answer. best would be to create a http://jsfiddle.net/ so that others can see and analyze the problem.

Comment: I would love to do that, but the html is serverside/database driven.

Comment: Can't you just copy the source of one example page? Apparently some style in the external css overwrites yours, seeing the complete html & css should make fixing it pretty easy

Comment: @svanelten, I've passing back json and html snippets data to javascript which inturn creates the html on the page.  So the generated html is not visible from view source.

Comment: Ok i see. Well your external stylesheet has no style rule for `.title`, so some combination overwrites your style. To make sure that your style takes predence, try make your rule more specific. If you have other elements that always wrap your `.title` elements, add them to the rule like this: `#container .something .title` to get a more specific rule.

Comment: @svanelten, perfect, that worked!!!  Please add that as an answer so it can be accepted.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok i see. Well your external stylesheet has no style rule for `.title`, so some combination overwrites your style. To make sure that your style takes predence, try to make your rule more specific. If you have other elements that always wrap your `.title` elements, add them to the rule like this: `#container .something .title` to get a more specific rule.